# How to conditionally format based on neighbour cell text?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting on a table like this:

```
 ╔════════╦════════╗
 ║ Editor ║  Type  ║
 ╠════════╬════════╣
 ║ john   ║ Fun    ║
 ║ doe    ║ Travel ║
 ║ mark   ║ Movies ║
 ╚════════╩════════╝
```

where I need to color both columns according to Editor rows content.
For example, if editor is `john` both Editor and Type need to be green, if `doe` red, etc., etc.

Of course in `Editor` column using simple "text is" conditional works flawlessly but in `Type` I tried indirect, address and several other formulas in the "Custom formula is" field.

What do I need to do?

Additionally, the columns repeat horizontally, like this:

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Editor ║  Type  ║ Editor ║  Type  ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ john   ║ Fun    ║ john   ║ Fun    ║
║ doe    ║ Travel ║ doe    ║ Travel ║
║ mark   ║ Movies ║ mark   ║ Movies ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

So I need a solution compatible with this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Select ColumnsA:D and Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
 =$A1="john"
```

Choose green for Formatting style and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Repeat with a new rule for each separate colour, so for red:

```
=$A1="doe"
```

If required, adjust `A1` and `Apply to range` to suit.

BTW Strictly speaking (despite much precedent) your Q is probably off topic here (though not necessarily at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Thanks! I will test later.
About the off topic thing, i saw a question about this topic here before, and it arent marked as off

Comment: After some time (sorry) i tested your answer. It works, but it only whatches for the content of the first "Name" column.

![This image](http://puu.sh/lJv9h/1fbabc228f.PNG/Capturar.PNG) shows the issue: Suppose the "CDC" column is equivalent to "Name", and "Tipo" is "Type". If in the first cell the name is "vico", all other cells become green. But i only want the "Type" column immediately at the right to exhibit this behaviour. Each pair need to be "independent" and exhibit the colour based on the Name content.

Comment: The top-left (the first) cell is B3.

I prefer to each pair to be "self-sustainable", in other words, each pair (Name - Type) bg color to be based in your own Name content.

Another thing desirable (but i think it could be achieved with same solution i was searching) is to, while the bg color would be based in the Name content, the font color would be based in Type content.

Comment: So would be interesting to make separed conditional formatting for EACH column? and then repeating in every column of the same kind (changing of course the references)?